# those in Hollywood advocating for new safety measures

Tags: verbs

This is a sentence from a [*The Atlatic* article](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2022/02/gun-safety-hollywood-alec-baldwin/622836/).

> If even those in Hollywood advocating **for** new safety measures can’t
> agree on the basic questions, how can anyone expect sweeping change?

I think the 'for' in bold could be removed from the sentence.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think "for" *should* be removed? By saying "should" you're suggesting that the preposition "for"  is either redundant or ungrammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you very much.

Comment: "Advocating" and "advocating for" are both used and have slightly different meanings.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Advocate" can be both a transitive and an intransitive verb.

The transitive use means '*to argue for*', so the use of 'for' is not needed.

When used as an intransitive verb, it means '*to act as an advocate*', so it is often necessary to state what they are advocating *for*.

Comment: Thank you very much.